# Why does my code jump to return1 even if the value in ebx is greater than the value in eax

Tags: assembly

So this is the code and it always jumps to return1 even if the value in ebx is greater than the value in eax

I tried using ret, but it causes a memory violation.

```
mov eax, 5
mov edx, 5
mov ebx, 11
add eax, edx
cmp eax, ebx
jg return1
mov eax, 0
return1:
mov eax, 1
```

I expect the output of "0" but the actual output is "1"

Comment: Can you explain what you tried with `ret`? Anyway, the way it is is an example of the usual problem: after `mov eax, 0`, `mov eax, 1` is also executed because you didn't tell it not to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code overwrites EAX register disregard the branch taken.

In the case of (EAX > EBX) the code executed will be:

```
mov eax, 0 // eax = 0
mov eax, 1 // eax = 1
```

Otherwise:

```
mov eax, 1 // eax = 1
```

Try to insert unconditional jump (jump) to the exit code immediately before "return1" label to eliminate overwriting of EAX register:

```
mov eax, 5
mov edx, 5
mov ebx, 11
add eax, edx
cmp eax, ebx
jg return1
mov eax, 0
jmp return2
return1:
mov eax, 1
return2:
```

Comment: You can also replace `jg return1
mov eax, 0
jmp return2
return1:
mov eax, 1
return2:` with the instructions `setg al` `movzx eax, al`